# UITextField in custom UITableViewCell - keyboard not dismiss

Tags: uitableview, keyboard-events, uikeyboard, custom-cell

I have custom UITableViewCell with UITextField. 
The problem is that i am not able to dismiss that keyboard.

In my TVC i have UITextFieldDelegate and in viewDidLoad method i implement:

```
customCell.textField.delegate = self;
```

and of course :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

     [customCell.textField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [customCell.textField resignFirstResponder];
     } return NO;
}
```

i tried implement this code into my CustomTableViewCell class.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already set the delegate of the textfield.

`-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;` takes a `textField` so you didnt need to recreate the cell just to access it because it is being passed to the delegate so use it directly.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;// or YES depending on what you trying to do
}
```

Comment: @M.Koptak ok , add a log `NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn is called!");` to make sure its being called and make sure you implemented the delegate

Comment: Is not called. Any idea why?

Comment: yes, you need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and try return YES

Comment: i have <UITextFieldDelegate> already implemented. Or you mean something special?

Comment: No this is what I meant, can you move this code and delegate to the custom cell class ?

Comment: Can be the problem that i have other class for my customCell and than my TVC don't know that my textField is edited?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58118/discussion-between-meda-and-m-koptak).

Comment: Nothing happened. I am little bit confused about this. Why that code is't being called??